# How to remove the icon in the titlebar?

Tags: osx, frames

Setting `frame-title-format` and `icon-title-format` to `nil` does not help.

[image]

Comment: You can try `(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'name nil)` and `(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'title nil)`. Note, that this has nothing to do with `mode-line-format`.

Comment: While I can appreciate the wish for a clean empty title bar, the icon can prove useful now and then: if you click and hold on it for a second you can drag-and-drop it on to another app, just as if you were dragging a file from the Finder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install emacsmacport:

`brew tap railwaycat/emacsmacport
brew install emacs-mac`

And then

`defaults write org.gnu.Emacs HideDocumentIcon YES`

Comment: I've being using this distribution already. And the `defaults` command changes nothing.

Comment: Ah, then you may need to install with the `--with-natural-title-bar` option.

Answer (score 16):

In emacs 26 you can set `ns-use-proxy-icon`

`(setq ns-use-proxy-icon nil)`

I was able to get a completely "clean" transparent title bar:

[image]

Download emacs 26 for mac, add the following config to your .emacs, and restart emacs.

```
    (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(ns-transparent-titlebar . t))
    (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(ns-appearance . dark)) ;; assuming you are using a dark theme
    (setq ns-use-proxy-icon nil)
    (setq frame-title-format nil)
```

Comment: This works very well. Except when using something like BetterSnapTool, the width and height of frame will show in the title bar somehow.